# How to create an atomated test case in C# by reading a void method in a DLL

Tags: c#, dll, methods, automated-tests

I know what VOID means in a method so please be patient.

I'm trying to create an automated tc using C# as follows:

i referenced the DLL file in my test project like this

```
corridor.CorridorApi reference = new corridor.CorridorApi();
```

And then i try to create the automated tc like this:

```
 [TestMethod]
    public void TestSubtractionisGood()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(my_expected_value, referencia.Connect(url, para1, para2, para3));
    }
```

Also i'm  not sure if the Assert method (AreEqual) is the most correct to use in this example.

Thank you for your answers in advanced

UPDATE:

here is my Connect method

```
procedure myAPI.Connect(const Url, customerGUID, keyboardGUID, Key:  WideString);
begin
FService := GetIBSI_SI_ServicePortType(false, Url);
FService.checkAlive;
FClientGUID := customerGUID;
FKeyGUID := KeyboardGUID;
SetKey(Key);
end;
```

Comment: What are you trying to test? In English, "when I XXX it should YYY"?

Comment: You have hinted that you want to test a void method, and you know what void means, but in your test case you mention an expected value - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to test if there was a successful connection with the 2nd system

Comment: @Alejo_Blue Testing that a connection was successful means that this is not a Unit Test, but an Integration test, which requires a different approach to verifying the code, and `Assert` is not the right approach in this case.

Comment: @Dai thank you for correcting me. Would you be so kind to provide an example of what would be the right approach for what i need? i just need to create an automated test cases that test connection is successful

Comment: You're testing a Delphi method with a C# unit-test?

Comment: What happens if the connection fails? Is an exception thrown?

Comment: That's right @Blorgbeard,. It is a Delphi method and i want to access it through a test case created on C#